# When using FCL(Flexible Collision Detection) Library to distance query for mesh model(.obj), there was a stack overflow

Tags: c++, collision-detection, stack-overflow

I want to try to learn use fcl library, but when i try to make a distance query, there was a stack overflow problem.
I follow the web readme tutorial interface to program.
https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl#interfaces

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fcl/math/bv/utility.h"
#include "fcl/narrowphase/collision.h"
#include "fcl/narrowphase/detail/gjk_solver_indep.h"
#include "fcl/narrowphase/detail/gjk_solver_libccd.h"
#include "fcl/narrowphase/detail/traversal/collision_node.h"
#include "fcl/narrowphase/continuous_collision.h"

#include "corecrt_math_defines.h"
#include "test_fcl_utility.h"

#include "fcl_resources/config.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace fcl;
using namespace Eigen;



int main()
{
    std::vector<fcl::Vector3f> p1, p2;
    std::vector<Triangle> t1, t2;

    fcl::test::loadOBJFile("OBJModel/cubic1.obj", p1, t1);
    fcl::test::loadOBJFile("OBJModel/cubic1.obj", p2, t2);

    typedef BVHModel<OBBRSSf> Model;
    shared_ptr<Model> arm0 = make_shared<Model>();
    shared_ptr<Model> arm1 = make_shared<Model>();

    arm0->beginModel();
    arm0->addSubModel(p1, t1);
    arm0->endModel();

    arm1->beginModel();
    arm1->addSubModel(p2, t2);
    arm1->endModel();



    Vector3f T0 = Vector3f(3.,3,3);

    Vector3f T1;
    T1 << 3., 0, 0;

    Transform3f tf0 = Transform3f::Identity();
    tf0.translation() = T0;

    Transform3f tf1 = Transform3f::Identity();
    tf1.translation() = T1;


    CollisionObjectf* obj0 = new CollisionObjectf(arm0, tf0);
    CollisionObjectf* obj1 = new CollisionObjectf(arm1, tf1);


    // set the distance request structure, here we just use the default setting
    DistanceRequestf request;
    // result will be returned via the collision result structure
    DistanceResultf result;
    // perform distance test
    distance(obj0, obj1, request, result);
    cout << result.min_distance << endl;
    
}
```

when i run **distance(obj0, obj1, request, result);**

```
Problem occured 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000002DD6403F70)。
```

I also find a [github code](https://github.com/HiroIshida/snippets/blob/a1c053d01f5e3ebaae4c79a998f1d34c1328be33/cpp/ext_example/fcl/main.cpp), it's similar to mine. I can't find anything different.

I checked out call stack, there are lots of distanceRecurse, but I can not understand why so many distanceRecurse were run, my model is just a cubic(2*2*2).here are the screen picture of CallStack.
[lots of distanceRecurse in stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHhFa.png)

[the last stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaC4O.png)

This is the Recurse function:

[distnaceRecurse function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs7gK.png)

Thank you so much to anyone who give me advice to solve my problem.

Comment: Run a debugger and get the stack trace. Paste it in the question.

Comment: @kiner_shah Thank you, I try to use callstack solve my problem but falied. I have update my debug detail.

Comment: Recursion causes stack overflow probably, you haven't handled some base cases (required to break from recursion) properly, or the inputs that you use is too large which leads to stack overflow. I would recommend use some iterative method instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FCL 0.6.1](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl/releases/tag/v0.6.1)
The version 0.6.1 can deal with this problem. It may be a bug now.